# Pegar variavel javascript e colocar no php

Tags: javascript, html

Como que faço pra pegar uma variavel enviada pelo input no javascript para php?
Pesquisei na net más não ta dando certo.
Obrigado pessoal!

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    funcaoJavascript = function(){
var valor = document.getElementById('id1').value;

}

</script>
```

PHP e o input:

```
<input type="text" id="id1" onchange="funcaoJavascript()"/>
<?php $x = "script>document.write(valor)</script>";
echo $x;
?>
```